# Alfresco share custom page can't use images

Tags: html, css, image, alfresco-share

As directed by this [link](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/tutorial-share-add-page.html) I have created a custom page for Alfresco Share to use as navigation. The jar file contains images and once again as directed its in `META-INF/images` (this part was sort of unclear what all should be there).
Upon further research I found out that META-INF is auto generated with a manifest but I am unsure a manifest would help me. 
Alright the issue I'm having is that I can't get the images out of the jar file for Alfresco Share. 
I've tried this @import url("/share/res/images/Concur.ng");
I've tried hard coding links to where they say it should end up

```
<src="http/serverIP/share/components/image/alfresco-share-logo.ng">
```

I tried doing it the way they wanted it done
`<i src="/res/images/ADPSelfPortal.png">` (or so I think).

`<i src="share/res/images/ADPSelfPortal.png">` tried both.

I need some guidance here if I really wanted to I could just drop the file of images somewhere randomly on the server and point to their location but if they aren't logged in they shouldn't have access to these resources. 
Sorry this is a mess I'm frustrated with this problem.

Comment: what Alfresco version are you talking about?

Comment: its alfresco community addition i believe 5.0, additionally its working now. the METAI-INF folder has to be packaged alongside the alfresco folder not inside it. That was unclear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the instructions were correct, the smallest typo in the name and syntax when creating the jar is extremely important for adding pages to alfresco. Although finding this information did prove difficult at the time. I mentioned in the comment above that the alfresco folder and the meta-inf folder have to be packaged in the same directory. This functionality is important so that alfresco finds all the proper supporting files. Any new files to add to the static folder must be put into the META-INF folder.